# Is the AuthToken generator unique enough?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, auth-token

What will happen once I generate say a million AuthTokens for users (on multiple devices).. should I be worried about uniqueness down the line?

The line that generates the token in the API is:

```
    def generate_key(self):
    unique = uuid.uuid4()
    return hmac.new(unique.bytes, digestmod=sha1).hexdigest()
```

It seems as though it's SHA1 so I'm assuming it should be OK but perhaps I should validate not only the token but perhaps an incoming device id or e-mail?

Any thoughts?

Comment: if it's standard implementation of uuid, chances for duplicate are pretty slim [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates)

Comment: Yea it uses uuid4() which I looked up here (http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html) it's the method to generate a random unique ID. It then takes a 'bytes' version of that (against SHA1) to create the actual token. Thank you for the Wiki link though. Was helpful.